# My array of sprites is not getting drawn on my renderwindow

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml

So I am trying to make a chessgame, and of course I am starting out with just making the board. For this I am creating a two-dimensional array like 8x8. Each tile has their own object sprite called tileSprite and I am trying to define them as 1/8th of the width and height of the screen, which has a fixed size of 1024x768. The textures that are loaded in are just 1 pixel black or white. The program gives no definitive error, but the drawn tiles aren't getting displayed onto my window, and all I see is a red screen, which I get from clearing the screen (following the standard clear/draw/display cycle of SFML).

```
#include "SFML/Window.hpp"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "SFML/Audio.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

bool playing = true;

class Textures {
public:
    static void loadTextures();

    sf::Texture static blackTile;
    sf::Texture static whiteTile;
};
/*---Class--Definitions----*/
sf::Texture Textures::blackTile;
sf::Texture Textures::whiteTile;
/*-------------------------*/

void Textures::loadTextures() {
    if (blackTile.loadFromFile("Images/blackTile.PNG")) {
        return;
    }
    else if (whiteTile.loadFromFile("Images/whiteTile.PNG")) {
        return;
    }
}

class ChessBoard_Tiles {
public:
    static void _initialize();
    static void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);

    enum TileStatus { EMPTY, OCCUPIED, HIGHLIGHTED };

    struct TileSlot {
        sf::Sprite tileSprite;
        TileStatus tileStatus;
    };

private:
    typedef std::array< std::array<TileSlot*, 8>, 8 > TileType;
    static TileType tileBoard;
};
/*-Class Definition that has to be called-*/
ChessBoard_Tiles::TileType ChessBoard_Tiles::tileBoard = ChessBoard_Tiles::TileType();

void ChessBoard_Tiles::_initialize() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            tileBoard[i][j] = new TileSlot();

            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                tileBoard[i][j]->tileSprite.setTexture(Textures::whiteTile);
            }
            else {
                tileBoard[i][j]->tileSprite.setTexture(Textures::blackTile);
            }

            tileBoard[i][j]->tileSprite.setPosition(128 * j, 96 * i);
            tileBoard[i][j]->tileSprite.setScale(128, 96);
            tileBoard[i][j]->tileStatus = EMPTY;
        }
    }
}

void ChessBoard_Tiles::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            window.draw(tileBoard[i][j]->tileSprite);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sf::RenderWindow renderWindow;
    renderWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(1024, 768), "Chess");

    Textures::loadTextures();
    ChessBoard_Tiles::_initialize();

    while (playing) {
        sf::Event currentEvent;
        renderWindow.pollEvent(currentEvent);

        if (currentEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            renderWindow.close();
            playing = false;
        }

        if (currentEvent.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
            if (currentEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                renderWindow.close();
                playing = false;
            }
        }

        renderWindow.clear(sf::Color::Red);
        std::cout << "Clear\n";

        ChessBoard_Tiles::draw(renderWindow);
        std::cout << "Draw\n";

        renderWindow.display();
        std::cout << "Display\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If anyone knows what is wrong then that would be a big help for me.. Otherwise I'd probably have to entirely remake this program, which I think should work so far, but I haven't the slightest idea why it doesn't. Big thanks in advance =)

EDIT: Read a little about how the sprites seem to disappear if the textures are running out of scope.. If this is the case, could that just be pointed out and then I can work on that, because I have tried so many different things by now that I feel like I'm just going in circles?

Comment: You can answer your own question, SO even encourages such behavior!

Comment: Use the answer box below, it serves this exact purpose. Then edit your question to remove the "Fixed it... ignore" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault was from the loadTextures() function, where I had forgotten to include the file extension of the file to be loaded, and I screwed the logic about the loadFromFile() function up so the program only continued when it couldn't load the file..